# Meaning of お支払いを希望される方

Tags: grammar, translation, questions

I am having trouble understanding the following sentence:

> クレジットカードによるお支払【しはら】いを希望【きぼう】される方【かた】は、次【つぎ】の注意【ちゅうい】をお読【よ】みください。

In particular, I am having trouble comprehending the first clause:

> クレジットカードによるお支払【しはら】いを希望【きぼう】される

From what I do understand, クレジットカードによるお支払いを希望される modifies 方.

From this, it seems to mean something like:

> Regarding a way to ["be hoped" / "be desired"] for credit card payments, please read the next warning.

"be hoped" / "be desired" comes from 希望される, the passive conjugation of 希望する.

Questions:

1. To confirm, クレジットカードによる modifies お支払い, and the resulting phrase means "credit card payment", right?
2. お支払いを希望する seems to mean "to hope for payment", but "to be hoped  for payment" and "way to be hoped for payment" sound somewhat bizarre. How can this phrase be broken down and translated? Also, can I infer the listener/reader to be the entity doing the hoping?
3. Ultimately, what does the sentence mean? How much of my translation is accurate? Even my resulting English translation doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

クレジットカードによる modifies お支払い and クレジットカードによるお支払いを希望される modifies 方. [方]{かた} means 人, someone or a person, or in this case, 'you', customers. The される in 希望される is not passive but honorific.

> To those who wish to / If you wish to pay by credit card, please read..

Comment: どうもありがとうございます! It makes much more sense after having it explained to me! \\(^_^)/

Comment: Is this される perhaps similar in function to なさる?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to that. (but お支払いを希望なさる方は sounds less polite than お支払いを希望される方は to me.)

Comment: I see, thanks! One more thing, is される considered more polite than なさる in general, or does it depend on the situation?

Comment: After a bit of research I think される is politer than なさる in most cases. なさる is more preferred in some cases, eg. 「ごゆっくりなさってください」(Please make yourself at home.) not 「ごゆっくりされてください」. And, なさる and される sound equally polite in 「どちらになさいますか？」「どちらにされますか？」(Which one would you like?)